# How did Rails generate this path from our model and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Ok I kind of understand this part: CRUD verbs and actions http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

and if I go to the route file of the example I have, I also see a **resources :orders** in it.

But now in the view of a partial names _carts I am seeing this code:

```
<%= button_to "Checkout" , new_order_path, method: :get %>
```

What confuses me is the **new_order_path**  ? Where did that come from?  What Rails convention rule is allowing us to right this? Especially where did that "new" come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `resources :orders` in the routes, Rails creates 7 routes for new, create, show, update, destroy, list, and edit. All of them are given names, and `new_order_path`/`new_order_url` is related to the new action.

These routes are described at the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

Answer (score 1):

Those path helpers are [automatically generated for resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls) defined in your `routes.rb`. You can check what route helpers are available by executing `rake routes` at the command line. They are shown in the left-most column in the table that prints out.

The general pattern of the paths that are created are like so by default:

- **new_{singular form of resource}_path** - Routes to `new` on GET
- **edit_{singular form of resource}_path** - Routes to `edit` on GET
- **{singular form of resource}_path** - Routes to `show` on GET, `destroy` on DELETE, `update` on PUT (Soon to be PATCH in Rails 4)
- **{plural form of resource}_path** - Routes to `index` on GET and `create` on POST.

There's also helpers that end in `_url` instead of `_path` that provide absolute URLs instead of relative paths. The particular action that is hit in your controller depends on the HTTP verb (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.) used when visiting those URLs.